# parameter to suppresswarnings for catching `Exception` in IntelliJ Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, pmd, suppress-warnings

I am using PMD and checkstyle and using code like below

```
public void testMethod() {
try {
            // do something
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error("Error updating benchmark {} state", benchmarkId, e);
            }
}
```

But its failing during quality check as `testmethod` is catching `Exception`. I want used `@SuppressWarnings("PMD.SignatureDeclareThrowsException")` but its not working and tried searching what should be the proper annotation to handle it but couldn't find it.

Let me know what should be proper `PMD` annotation to suppress warning for catching `exception` in Intellij Idea.

Comment: With your cursor over the warning, use ALT + ENTER keys and then use the right arrow key to open a sub-menu. That sub menu has options like "Suppress for line" or "Suppress for method" and others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SignatureDeclareThrowsException` is the rule that forbids doing method declarations such as `void myMethod() throws Exception`.

Here, you are probably being reported of `AvoidCatchingGenericException` on this block (check [this](https://pmd.github.io/pmd-5.7.0/pmd-java/rules/java/strictexception.html#AvoidCatchingGenericException)). Therefore, you should probably use `@SuppressWarnings("PMD.AvoidCatchingGenericException")` instead.

Comment: Note that for chckstyle this is `@SuppressWarnings({"checkstyle:IllegalCatch"})`.